# Are radioactive decays truly random?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, determinism, randomness

By truly random I mean that **IF** we knew the position and velocity of every particle in radioactive isotope, could we predict when the decay would happen?

Comment: Yes, it is truly random. At this scale, quantum mechanics dominate the behaviour of the nucleus. At best, you can get a probability of the decay. (Also, you can't know precisely the position and velocity of the particles inside the nucleus, due to Heisenberg's principle of incertitude).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is radioactive decay spontaneous or random?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105107/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63811/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71509/2451 and links therein.